# Crucible and multiple mercurial clones handling

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, atlassian-crucible

I was wondering if Crucible can handle the following scenario with Mercurial.
How do you use DVCSs with Crucible in such a scenario?

There are several issues in a project, for each issue a developer makes a clone of the project from repo "stable-build", to repo "dev-0001" (on a local sharing server). 
Clone is named according to the issue : "dev-0001" for example.

Now from there a developer clones on his local machine into clone "local-dev-0001", makes the changes and then pushes to "dev-0001".

Some other developer wants to review the changes in repo "dev-0001" before the dev that implemented 0001 can push to "stable-build".

What I tried is to set up Crucible for a repo (a separate test clone "test-crucible" directly from "stable-build". It took a loong time on a very power full machine, about 5 days.

My question is : how can Crucible and Mercurial be set up so that one can create reviews for the "dev-0001" clone befor eit is pushed to a somewhat central server, withouth waiting 5 days for Crucible to parse the "dev-0001" repo from the start, and maybe use the information of it's parent ? Is this already done does it need some sort of plugin?

I can offer more clarity for the scenario if that was a bit hazzy,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm discovering the answer might be no for this workflow without altering it. Also found this for who is searching the answer for this :

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/8798/does-latest-version-support-revieiwing-from-local-repositories-using-mercurial

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out a satisfactory answer for my case, a pre-commit patch file could be used,
obtained from making a diff in "dev-0001" before pushing to "stable-build" with : "hg outgoing -p > patch-0001"

Comment: Precommit reviews have some downsides - they're not associated with the changeset once you do push it.